# Inicializacion de valores en struct - C++

Tags: c++

la cosa esta en yo creo un struct el:

```
struct salari{
unsigned int base;
unsigned int dietes;
unsigned int total=base+dietes;
};
```

y despues al hacer el main:

```
int main(){
salari a;
a.base=100;
a.dietes=2;
cout<<a.base<<endl;
cout<<a.dietes<<endl;
cout << a.total << endl;
}
```

al compilarlo asi

```
g++ base_dades.cc -o base_dades.e
```

me sale este warning

```
warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
unsigned int total=base+dietes;
```

donde al ejecutarlo el output es :

```
100
2
4196768
```

alguien sabe el porque pasa esto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que nos presentas se debe a lo siguiente:

`unsigned int total=base+dietes;`

Tu estas tratando de inicializar el valor ***total*** siendo que ***base*** y ***dietes*** no tienen un valor designado, asi que el compilador te indica esta advertencia, ya que a diferencia de las clases las estructuras por defecto no se pueden inicializar en la declaracion, **PERO** Existe una solucion.

*Voila* La solucion:

```
struct salari{
  unsigned int base;
  unsigned int dietes;
  unsigned int total;

  salari(){
   base = 0;
   dietes = 0;
   total = base + dietes;
  }
};
```

Esta es una manera de hacer una especie de `constructor` para las estructuras en C++, con esta puedes inicializar cada uno de los valores contenidos en la estructura, sin que te arroje ningun error.

Luego de esto la salida es:

```
100
2
0
```

En este caso nos arroja 0 al final porque este es el valor con el que lo hemos inicializado, debes asignarle el valor que tu deseas posteriormente, ya que la estructura no actualiza sus valores cada vez que tu la llamas, es decir si tu le dices que un elemento sera igual a la suma de otros, ese es el valor de la **declaracion e inicializacion**, posteriormente debes cambiarlo segun tus necesidades.

Comment: No. La advertencia es por usar una característica de C++11 sin tener los flags de C++11 activados.

Answer (score 3):

En C++, al contrario que C# y Java, no estaba permitido inicializar variables miembro en el lugar de la declaración. Así fue hasta que en agosto de 2011 fue aprobado el estándar C++11 añadiendo esta funcionalidad al comportamiento estándar del lenguaje.

[[Aquí]](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#member-init) tienes la descripción de esta funcionalidad en la página de [Bjarne Stroustrup](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bjarne_Stroustrup) (En Inglés), recibe el nombre técnico de *Inicialización de miembros en clase* ("*In-class member initializers*").

#### El compilador gcc.

La Inicialización de miembros en clase está soportada en gcc desde la versión [4.7](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html)<sup>1</sup>. Para dar uso a las características de C++11 debe activarse el modo C++11 del compilador añadiendo el parámetro `-std=c++11` a la orden de compilación, tal y como te indica la alarma que obtienes al compilar:

> ```
> warning: non-static data member initializers only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
> unsigned int total=base+dietes;
> ```

Así que deberías dejar de tener esa alarma si compilas de esta manera:

> ```
> g++ base_dades.cc -o base_dades.e -std=c++11
> ```

Seguramente tienes una versión de gcc igual o superior a 4.7, por lo que el código compila pese a ser código erróneo en estándares de C++ previos a C++11. Como el parámetro de compilación `-std=c++11` no se añade por defecto, te muestra una alarma (en lugar de error) por ser capaz de compilar el código pese a la ausencia de la opción de compilación adecuada.

#### Funcionamiento de la Inicialización de miembros en clase.

Tengo la sensación (corrígeme si me equivoco) que esperabas que la salida de tu código fuese:

> ```
> 100
> 2
> 102
> ```

Pero esto no sucedería así ya que la instrucción `unsigned int total=base+dietes;` se ejecuta en el momento de la **construcción de la instancia** de `salari`, es decir: en el mismo momento en que la instrucción `salari a;` es ejecutada.

Dado que los miembros `base` y `dietes` no tienen valor inicial, su valor es indeterminado<sup>2</sup> pero no pocas veces es un valor diferente de 0. Así que el valor `4196768` que has obtenido es el resultado de sumar dos valores de memoria al azar en el momento de construir `a`.

Para que el `total` se actualice automáticamente al asignar `base` y `dietes` deberías usar funciones de asignación:

```
struct salari{
unsigned int base = 0;
unsigned int dietes = 0;
unsigned int total = 0;

void assigna_base(unsigned int valor){
base = valor;
total = base + dietes;
}

void assigna_dietes(unsigned int valor){
dietes = valor;
total = base + dietes;
}
};
```

Así, tu `main` con estas funciones:

```
int main(){
salari a;
a.assigna_base(100);
a.assigna_dietes(2);

std::cout << a.base   << '\n'
          << a.dietes << '\n'
          << a.total  << '\n';

return 0;
}
```

Daría esta salida

> ```
> 100
> 2
> 102
> ```

Fíjate que he inicializado a `0` todos los miembros de `salari` con la Inicialización de miembros en clase.

Molta sort Pol, fins un altra :)

---

<sup>1</sup>[[Aquí]](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) puedes ver las características añadidas a C++ y en qué versión de gcc fueron implementadas.

<sup>2</sup>Todo dato no inicializado, contiene como valor aquello que contuviera la memoria que se le asigna, que podría ser cualquier valor.